# Saving an Xdocument to location where it was opened?

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-8

I have created an Xdocument that is edited in the line of code below, but want to save the edited version of this file and overwrite the first version. Voicecmd.xml is located in the root of the solution, I didn't put it into any folders or anything.

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("voicecmd.xml");
var ns = XNamespace.Get("http://schemas.microsoft.com/voicecommands/1.0");
xDoc.Root.Element(ns + "CommandSet").Element(ns + "CommandPrefix").Value = "Phone2";
```

I tried xDoc.Save, but I couldn't do xDoc.Save("voicecmd.xml"). I tried messing around with filestreams, but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Why not? What happened?

Comment: It requires a Stream to save, when trying to save in the same manner as I used load, I just get the line underlined with an invalid arguments error. I just don't understand how to use streams and am looking for some help with them.

Comment: @SLaks MSDN says `XDocument.Save` with `string` parameter is not available on Windows Phone.

Answer (score 0):

Can you expand on the exact error you are getting when you call save? Below is a link to the Save method and all of its overloads. Take a look at the save(string) option. Again, if that link doesn't get you going in the right direction and you still are seeing errors, please post them.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.save(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: As MarcinJuraszek said, String is simply not available on the phone, so I get these two errors while trying to use it: 1) The best overloaded method match for 'System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Save(System.Xml.XmlWriter)' has some invalid arguments and 2) Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.Xml.XmlWriter'

. So what i'm looking for is an alternative, not how to use string.